# Shared memory with mpi

Tags: python, mpi, shared-memory

I am trying to have a shared memory block using `multiprocessing` to contain a `numpy` array accessible to processes created using `mpi4py`. A basic tutorial is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory). I made an simple code to implement it in the following script and run it from the terminal with `mpirun -np 2 python myscript.py`.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
pid = comm.Get_rank()
npros = comm.Get_size()

npts = 10
dtyp = np.int64

if pid == 0:
    arr = np.arange(npts, dtype=dtyp)
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=arr.nbytes, name='trial')
    brr = np.ndarray(arr.shape, dtype=arr.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    brr[:] = arr[:]
    del arr

comm.barrier()

if pid == 1:
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='trial')
    crr = np.ndarray((npts), dtype=dtyp, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
    print(crr)

comm.barrier()

if pid == 1:
    del crr
    existing_shm.close()

comm.barrier()

if pid == 0:
    del brr
    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
```

However, it throws back some warning

```
/home/peedaruos/miniconda/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
/home/peedaruos/miniconda/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:229: UserWarning: resource_tracker: '/trial': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/trial' warnings.warn('resource_tracker: %r: %s' % (name, e))
```

Not sure if there is a problem or could get serious down the line..

Comment: Why do you want to use multiprocessing-SharedMemory with MPI? Seems like a contradiction in your design - the whole point of MPI is to parallelize out onto systems too large to share the same ram.

Comment: I mean, you do all the trouble of using MPI, but then your program only works when the ranks can share memory.

Comment: That being said, your code looks correct and I can't figure out whats wrong. Don't have MPI right now, and I cannot reproduce your problem without it. And the warnings are contradictory - it tells you 'trial' is not cleaned up yet it also tells you it can't find 'trial'. There is a deeper problem here.

Comment: Not really, the processes created with mpi should be able to run independently (I know they have their own ram space). There are possible benefits on using shared memory space between those processes as well, e.g. (1) if the processes just need to access some large data (read-only) from the disk to proceed, one might want to load the data into a shared memory block instead of each MPI process loading the same large data burdening the system, (2) instead of passing around messages like arrays that sync the computations, they could share the info though a common array, could be marginally faster

Comment: I know the benefits of shared memory parallelism. But MPI is specifically for the case where you don't want to do shared memory parallelism. You bought an off-road-vehicle and only drive it on the highway.

Comment: Your point (1): MPI has its own filesystem-access-abstractions specifically to do what you want, MPI-IO. Hdf5 is built on top of it. Your point (2): That is true on a single desktop-machine, but on a cluster, that would make the access to the array slow, defeating the whole point. If it is even possible to create a shared-memory-segment on a cluster - I doubt it.

Comment: (1) Might be going bit off-topic: I am wondering whether with a parallel build of HDF5, reading a large dataset by, say N mpi processes leaves the same memory footprint as that of a shared memory design or something N times of that one (I will be happy to know if the former is the case). (2) Partly agreed for the cluster thing- but note, even mpi needs to have a fast interconnect to pass messages across nodes. Probably a hybrid design is also possible, but here I am worried about the above script which I expected to have worked, at least going by the docs.

Comment: Yes, with hdf5 and MPI-IO, every rank only reads a portion of the data, it is not duplicated everywhere. Some metadata of course will be redundant. Shared-memory / message-passing designs exist and make sense. But in those you typically don't have ranks sharing memory, you have ranks that are made up of multiple processes. Haven't done it with python, but with C and OpenMP it works fine.

Comment: So, I am confused now.. if every rank only reads only a portion of the data (your first line), how does it access the full data which it would need to do the computation

Comment: yes, a rank usually does not have all data in mpi, every rank only sees a portion, because the whole data is too big. That is the difficulty, the potential and also the fun of message-passing parallelism. You need to arrange your program to cope with that.

Comment: @julaine You are aware that MPI itself has a mechanism for shared memory? The possibility to share a read-only dataset, even if only inside a node, cuts down greatly on memory demand.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I know of MPI-Windows but they don't seem to be very popular from what I have seen. They are a comparatively new and exotic feature that I did not want to bring into the discussion here.

Comment: @julaine Please read up on the last 10 years of MPI. Windows are involved, but there is actual shared memory. One process can get a `double*` pointer (or whatever type) to the memory of another process.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing to different modes of parallel programming.

1. You start this program as MPI, meaning that two python processes are running. One process then creates a multiprocessing.shared_memory buffer. And then there is no way for the other process to find that buffer.
2. Normally you'd start one python process, it creates a shared buffer, adn then you spawn multiple multiprocessing processes that read that buffer. Obviously they can see the buffer because they get it from their parent. In your scenario there is no parent.

Comment: No. multiprocessing.shared_memory does not require being created on some parent. The documentation that OP linked creates and uses the buffer from two independent interactive shells.